# Using AFNetworking 2.0 with background tasks

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm having issues implementing background tasks using AFURLSessionManager.
I'm creating a new AFHTTPSessionManager with BaseURL and SessionConfiguration, using `NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:` and using the convenience method to create a POST request.

When I run my app, the first request is sent normally, but the second one returns `A background URLSession with identifier {ID} already exists!` and it crashes the app.

I've watched Apple's WWDC 2013 videos and they suggest you to create the Session Configuration only once, by using

```
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.yourcompany.appId.BackgroundSession"];
    session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
});
```

However there `session` property for AFURLSessionManager is set as readonly and there is no way for me to pass a custom NSURLSession, only a NSURLSessionConfiguration, that is created inside `AFURLSessionManager:init`:

```
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:self.operationQueue];
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong, but how else can I support background tasks using AFNetworking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that you cannot instantiate a new `AFHTTPSessionManager` and then change its `session` to reference some singleton `NSURLSession`. So, instead, you should make the `AFHTTPSessionManager` object, itself, the shared instance which you can reuse throughout the app.

At the [end of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21359684/1271826), I provide an example of using AFNetworking for background sessions.

Comment: I guess you can, but I wouldn't bother unless there was a compelling need. Feels like premature optimization to me...

Comment: Late comment: My app does regular downloads (user prompted) using a shared `AFHTTPSessionManager` object, and I'd like to add background updates. Should I create another `AFHTTPSessionManager` for this? Or is it possible to change the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` on the fly?

Comment: Yes, you'll need separate `AFHTTPSessionManager` (or `AFURLSessionManager`) for that. You cannot change the [`configuration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSession/configuration) on the fly.