# GCDWebServer handlers for background file transfer (Not GCDWebUploader)

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, file-transfer, backgrounding, gcdwebserver

Has anybody already tried to implement an handler for GET requests (the same question for POST method) without using the included (and cool) GCDWebUploader?

I need the server to respond to a GET request `http://local/download/filename.ext` uploading the file to the client.

I am conforming the request to the code "BackgroundSessionManager" (available here: [AFNetworking 2.0 and background transfers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350125/afnetworking-2-0-and-background-transfers)) and it get sent and triggered no worries.

The log I'm getting server side reads so:

```
[DEBUG] Did start background task
[DEBUG] Connection received 248 bytes on socket 14
[DEBUG] Connection on socket 14 preflighting request "GET /download/file.ext with 248 bytes body
[DEBUG] Connection on socket 14 processing request "GET /download/file.ext" with 248 bytes body
[EXCEPTION] *** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: value parameter is nil
[DEBUG] Did close connection on socket 14
```

I cannot work out how to set up the handler in order not to care about non-existent query to parse from JSON.

```
[webServer addHandlerForMethod:@"GET" path:@"/download" requestClass:[GCDWebServerRequest class] processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse *(GCDWebServerRequest* request) {
        __strong AppDelegate* strongSelf = weakSelf;
        NSLog(@"request for download is %@", request);

        return [strongSelf downloadFile:request];
    }];
```

Comment: It looks like you are using or adding handlers to a GCDWebUploader instance instead of using a GCDWebServer one. That would explain the NSJSONSerialization exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this code removed in order to make it work:

```
/*
 // Add a handler to respond to GET requests
[webServer addDefaultHandlerForMethod:@"GET"
                             requestClass:[GCDWebServerRequest class]
                        asyncProcessBlock:^(GCDWebServerRequest* request, GCDWebServerCompletionBlock completionBlock) {

                            __strong AppDelegate* strongSelf = weakSelf;
.....
*/

[webServer addHandlerForMethod:@"GET" path:@"/download" requestClass:[GCDWebServerRequest class] processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse *(GCDWebServerRequest* request) {
    __strong AppDelegate* strongSelf = weakSelf;
    NSLog(@"request for download is %@", request);

    return [strongSelf downloadFile:request];
}];
```

Commented out the default handler that was taking over and expecting a JSON packet anyhow.

**UPDATE**

To achieve background file transfer with GCDWebServer and NSURLSessions (even with AFNetworking) best way to me was to instantiate a GET handler with MatchBlock as follows:

```
[webServer addHandlerWithMatchBlock:^GCDWebServerRequest *(NSString* requestMethod, NSURL* requestURL, NSDictionary* requestHeaders, NSString* urlPath, NSDictionary* urlQuery) {

        if (![requestMethod isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
            return nil;
        }
        if (![urlPath hasPrefix:@"/download"]) {
            return nil;
        }
        return [[GCDWebServerRequest alloc] initWithMethod:requestMethod url:requestURL headers:requestHeaders path:urlPath query:urlQuery];

    } processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse *(GCDWebServerRequest* request) {

        GCDWebServerResponse* response = nil;

        NSString* filePath = [[weakSelf applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[request.path stringByRemovingPercentEncoding]];
        NSString* fileType = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL] fileType];
        if (fileType) {
            if ([fileType isEqualToString:NSFileTypeRegular]) {
                    // always allow ranges in our requests
                    response = [GCDWebServerFileResponse responseWithFile:filePath byteRange:request.byteRange];
                    [response setValue:@"bytes" forAdditionalHeader:@"Accept-Ranges"];
            }
        }
        if (response) {
            response.cacheControlMaxAge = 360;
        } else {
            response = [GCDWebServerResponse responseWithStatusCode:kGCDWebServerHTTPStatusCode_NotFound];
        }
        return response;

    }];
```