# AFHTTPSessionManager block is not called when app is on background

Tags: ios, background, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, nsurlsessionconfiguration

My app get a silent push, then do some http request in background using AFNetworking,but it didn't enter the complete block, code is:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
[manager GET:urlString
  parameters:nil
     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"response objece:%@", responseObject);
     }
     failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
     }];
```

then I found maybe I could use NSURLSessionConfiguration to config the session:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.company.backgroundDownloadSession"];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
[manager GET:urlString
  parameters:nil
     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"response objece:%@", responseObject);
     }
     failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
     }];
```

but AFNetworking crash says:'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Data tasks are not supported in background sessions.'
What should I do? And I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Proper background `NSURLSessionConfiguration` requires `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` or `NSURLSessionUploadTask`. The `GET` method, though, creates `NSURLSessionDataTask`.

   To use download or upload tasks, you'll have to build your request separately, and then leverage [`AFURLSessionManager`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.0/Classes/AFURLSessionManager.html) to issue download or upload. Having said that, you can, though, create requests using the various request serializers, if you're trying to create HTTP GET/POST style requests. Just use the `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` method `requestWithMethod`.

   For a basic introduction to using AFNetworking in conjunction with background `NSURLSessionConfiguration`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21359684/1271826. You'll have to marry that with the `requestWithMethod`, discussed above.

   Note, be wary about using the task-specific completion blocks (because the tasks continue even if the app is terminated and these blocks are long gone). As the AFNetworking documentation for the background download tasks says:

   > **Warning:** If using a background `NSURLSessionConfiguration` on iOS, these blocks will be lost when the app is terminated. Background sessions may prefer to use `setDownloadTaskDidFinishDownloadingBlock:` to specify the URL for saving the downloaded file, rather than the destination block of this method.
2. If you're making a modest request, it may be easier to just ask the OS for a little time to do so if the user happens to leave your app while the request is still in progress. See *Executing Finite-Length Tasks* section of [App Programming Guide for iOS: Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

   Bottom line, before issuing the request, do something like:

   ```
   UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

   bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
       // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
       // stopped or ending the task outright.
       [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
       bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];
   ```

   And then in the completion block of the request, you can terminate the background task:

   ```
   if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
       [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
       bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }
   ```

   This is only good for finite length tasks, but it probably much easier than trying to do background `NSURLSessionConfiguration`.

Comment: It's just a few http request,so the second suggestion is exactly what I want, thanks very much,you are a life saver!

Comment: @rob when app is terminated and i want to connect user and get online user in XMPP server than How can i connect ?

Comment: If you want to perform requests while the app is not running, the only way to do that is background fetch. See [Downloading Content in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5) in the _App Programming Guide for iOS._ Note, you don't have control as to when the server is called, but you do have this mechanism for downloading data in the background.